# insert at third node new childs c# XML

Tags: c#, xml, file, extract

i have this function

```
 private void ProcesNode(XmlNode node, string parentPath, string path, string first, string second, string BuiltUnit, string item, dynamic queries  )
    {

        if (!node.HasChildNodes || ((node.ChildNodes.Count == 2) && (node.FirstChild is System.Xml.XmlText)))
        {
            comanda_cmd = first + "/" + parentPath + second + "/" + parentPath + "/" + node.Attributes["Name"].Value;
            //string status = RunCommand(comanda_cmd + "/project.pj /n");

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {

                comanda_cmd = first + "/" + parentPath + second + "/" + parentPath + "/" + node.Attributes["Name"].Value;
        //with parenthPath and node.Attributes["Name"].Value create a new comanda_cnmd  
                //string status = RunCommand(comanda_cmd + "/project.pj /n");//this will execute comanda_cmd

            // when i arrive at the third child i want to do something 
            //the second child attribute can be the same with the third child attribute

             foreach (var ele in queries)
                if (node.Attributes["Name"].Value == ele)
                {

                    status = RunCommand(comanda1 + "/" + ele + comanda2 + "/" + ele + "/src/project.pj /n");
                    status = RunCommand(comanda1 + "/" + ele + comanda2 + "/" + ele + "/doc/project.pj /n");
                    status = RunCommand(comanda1 + "/" + ele + comanda2 + "/" + ele + "/tst/project.pj /n");
                }

                ProcesNode(child, parentPath + "/" + node.Attributes["Name"].Value, path, first, second, BuiltUnit, item, queries);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run this function I go through each node in xml and realize an order for CMD composed by parentPath and node.Attributes["Name"].Value. When i arrive at the third child i want to do something. How i know that the node is the third?
This is the XML

```
    <unit>
  <Dir Name="rte">
    <Dir Name="rte">
      <Dir Name="src" />
    </Dir>
    <Dir Name="rte_cdd">
      <Dir Name="src" />
    </Dir>
    <Dir Name="rte_ecal">
      <Dir Name="src" />
    </Dir>
    <Dir Name="rte_serv">
      <Dir Name="src" />
    </Dir>
  </Dir>
</unit>
```

i tried to create a list of all nodes of level three with the code below but when the second child attributes ("rte")is equal with the third child attributes ("rte") the if is executed and the command is executed for the second child.

```
var tst = XElement.Load(build_units_xmls[el]);
 var thirdLevelChildren = tst
  .Elements("Dir")
  .Elements("Dir")
  .Attributes("Name")
  .Select(f => f.Value);
```

What should i do ?

Comment: Bad design.  You should never have nested tags in xml with the same tag name.

Comment: @jdweng that's a rather bizarre assertion. How would you model a tree structure with that constraint?

Comment: This sounds like an [x y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you're actually trying to do rather than how you've tried to solve it?

Comment: Charles : I would make the name the tag.